# GWT: AcceptsOneWidget vs Composite vs IsWidget

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

GWT has a lot of similarly-named (and *seemingly* similarly-purposed) types:

- `Widget`
- `AcceptsOneWidget`
- `Composite`
- `IsWidget`
- `SimplePanel`

When/where is it appropriate to use each of these? What is their relationship to the `RootPanel`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's first separate interfaces from classes.

Interfaces are great for mocking (thus allowing for testing your app without the need for the sluggish `GWTTestCase`):

- `IsWidget`: when all you need is a *handle* on a widget, without depending on the `Widget` class. This is typically used with MVP as a way to represent the *view*.
- `AcceptsOneWidget`: when you need a placeholder for a single widget (in the form of an `IsWidget`). This is typically used with Activities, to insert the *view* (`IsWidget`) into the given *slot* (`AcceptsOneWidget`).

The classes you list all extend `Widget`, so they rely on JSNI and (most of the time) need to run in a *GWT environment* (for unit tests, that means a `GWTTestCase`):

- `Widget`: the base of all widgets. Implements `IsWidget` returning itself from `asWidget()`.
- `Composite`: a base class when you need to create a widget built from other widgets while hiding their implementation. While you could extend an existing widget, it's generally better to hide it inside a `Composite` so you only expose the API you need/want to expose. `Composite` is about "composition rather than inheritance" and *encapsulation*. Examples of composites in standard widgets include `TabPanel` (built from a `TabBar` and `DeckPanel`), `DateBox` (built from a `TextBox` and `DatePicker` in a `PopupPanel`), `ValueListBox` that wraps a `ListBox` or `ValuePicker` that wraps a `CellList`. In many cases, given that panels accept `IsWidget` children, you could simply implement `IsWidget` rather extend `Composite`, but it's sometimes useful to have a *true* `Widget`.
- `SimplePanel` a panel that implements `AcceptsOneWidget`, useful as a *slot* when using activities (but you could also easily implement `AcceptsOneWidget` to insert into any kind of panel)

That being said, Google recently open-sourced [GWT-Mockito](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito) that plugs Mockito into `GWT.create()` and uses *classloader magic* to rewrite JSNI methods and remove `final` modifiers so you can directly use widgets in tests without the need for `GWTTestCase` or MVP.

So, all in all, it depends how you approach your code, how you architecture your app. If you use MVP, stick to depending on interfaces only (`IsWidget`, `AcceptsOneWidget`) in your *presenter* so you can easily mock your view in your tests.
Otherwise, or if you want a "simplified MVP" where the view is a UiBinder template, try GWT-Mockito for your tests and directly use widgets.
Of course, you can mix both approaches in the same application. And in any case, build your own widgets as `Widget`s for low-level things (rarely needed), and `Composite`s or `IsWidget`s for everything else, rather than extending existing widgets.

Answer (score 4):

You have got all mixed up.

**Widget**: It allow you to interact with the users. (e.g. [Button](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Button.html))

**Panels**: These are widgets that can contain other panels/widgets. Can be referred as container of widgets.

**AcceptsOneWidget**: Implemented by panels which will accept only one widget. (e.g [SimplePanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html))

**Composite**: A type of widget that can wrap another widget, hiding the wrapped widget's methods. The composite is useful for creating a single widget out of an aggregate of multiple other widgets contained in a single panel.

**IsWidget**: An interface implemented by almost all known widgets. It Provides access to that widget.

**SimplePanel**: A panel which contains only one widget.

**RootPanel**: Is the base panel to which all other panels are added.

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik (+1) - a few followup questions: (1) both Panels and Composites seem to be containers of 1+ Widgets: so when is it appropriate to use each of them? And (2) Is adding 1+ Panel to the Root Panel required for the UI to be displayed in the browser? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) Composites are not containers but wrappers. Basically, you would use them to create custom widgets. Panels are used to add widgets. 
2) You can add 1 or more panels to Root panel, but I would suggest you to use a Flow panels(HTML Div equivalent) or VerticalPanel(HTML table equivalent) as a container, and add that container to the RootPanel.